# Xamarin Forms for Android Tv Application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, television

I developed an application that has different pages, the first page contains some buttons to navigate to other pages
I run it in my mobile, it works fine, and I run it on my tv (Andoird Tv), it runs but I can't click on buttons to navigate to others page by REMOTE CONTROL

How can I handle keys remote control in my app Xamarin forms

Thank's

Comment: go through this controllers to control through remote control https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/controllers

Comment: @khaloud1980, there are one thread that may be helpful to you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963749/using-remote-control-for-android-tv-application

Answer (score -1):

1. Press tab key to make your Button focused.
2. Then you can use REMOTE CONTROL to switch focus and click.

Comment: I see MAUI in preview version seems solved this problem. It can select button by Dpad. So let's wait....